# queue does not name a type error for RWSlistCollectablesQueue

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

I am working in solaris to Linux migration.I am using a roguewave class **RWSlistCollectablesQueue**
And an object of this rogue wave Queue is declared as below :

```
Queue queue;
```

which throws the below error -

> error : Queue does not name a type

The functions being called in the c program are :

```
queue.clearAndDestroy()     
queue.entries()         
queue.append()
queue.isEmpty()         
queue.get()
```

What could be the reason for this error?Any suggestions or alternative for this issue/

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-3702/Sli_7065.htm it looks like `Queue` is just a typedef for `RWSlistCollectablesQueue`. Just brainstorming: Does using that type name explicitly work? Have you included a header that should define it? Is it inside a namespace?

Comment: Instead of asking what causes `Queue` to not name a type, I would approach this from the opposite direction and try to prove that `Queue` does name a type. Find the definition under Solaris, which then tells you where to look under Linux.

Comment: Yes,Queue is a typedef and i have included the header queuecol.h